# Likelihood of 2 being a liar in Miller Rabin test for large number (e.g. 1000+ bits)

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

I have written some working code to generate RSA key pairs using the Miller-Rabin primality test. All of the generated keys pass the openssl rsa -check function, meaning that (among other things) openssl agrees that P and Q are both prime. For a 2048 bit key, P and Q are 1024-bit primes.

The Miller-Rabin algorithm is configured to run up to 64 rounds for numbers for which no witnesses for a composite candidate (c) are found. The first 14 rounds use fixed bases (the first 14 prime numbers), and the next 50 rounds use values from a PRNG in the range $2 \le c \le (2^k-2)$ where $k$ is the number of bits in the key

When a round using some base identifies $c$ as possibly prime, but a subsequent round using a different base finds $c$ to be composite, the candidate is what's known as a strong pseudoprime number. Bases which incorrectly identify $c$ as possibly prime are called liars, and this situation only happens when $c$ is a strong pseudoprime.

In analyzing the operation of my implementation of the Miller-Rabin algorithm, I notice that it has never come across any bases which are found to be liars. I have run over 30,000 prime number searches for 512 and 1024-bit prime numbers with nary a liar to be found.

If a strong pseudoprime value is encountered, several rounds with different bases may required to root it out, and the probability of a pseudoprime fooling $k$ rounds of Miller-Rabin is said to be $4^{-k}$. In the above example, with $k=64$, that amounts to a probability of $2^{-64} \approx 10^{-39}$, which is so small as to be zero.

But this left me wondering, why did the process never find a strong pseudoprime in over 30,000 runs, and is there any point if performing all those extra rounds if a strong pseudoprime is never going to pop up?

A common estimate of the number of primes less than some value, $x$ is this:

$$\Pi(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x}.$$

When working with RSA keys, $x$ is usually a large power of two less one, so we can approximate the fraction of those numbers less than $x$ which are prime. For $x=2^{1024}$, the fraction is $1/(\ln(2^{1024})) \approx 1/710$. When looking through random values to find a 1024-bit prime, it will take about 710 attempts on average. It's actually more than that because we're not accepting values less than $2^{1023}$, but this difference is not important for this discussion.

Since $x$ is such a large number, in computing probabilities it is computationally convenient to work with logarithms of these values.

$$\ln(x) = \ln(2^k - 1) \approx k \ln(2),$$

and

$$\ln \Pi(x) = \ln(x) - \ln( \ln(x) ).$$

There's an article by Carl Pomerance, "[On the Distribution of Pseudoprimes](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-37-156/S0025-5718-1981-0628717-0/S0025-5718-1981-0628717-0.pdf)" which gives an upper bound to the number of pseudoprimes less than "x", denoted by $P(x)$ in the article. Taking the logarithm of that formula yields this:

$$\ln( P(x) ) <  \ln(x) - \frac{\ln(x) \ln( \ln( \ln(x) ) )}{2 \ln( \ln(x) )}.$$

Since the implemented prime search algorithm never ran across a strong pseudoprime, these formulas can answer the question: what is the ratio of the count of true primes less than $x$ to the count of strong pseudoprimes less than $x$?

$$\ln \frac{\Pi(x)}{P(x)} = - \ln( \ln(x) ) +  \frac{\ln(x) \ln( \ln( \ln(x) ) )}{2 \ln( \ln(x) )} $$

The value of this ratio expressed as a power of 10 rather than as a natural logarithm for 512 and 1024 bit numbers is about $10^{21}$ and $10^{41}$ respectively. Strong pseudoprimes are so outnumbered by primes that the odds of ever finding one are essentially zero for key lengths currently used in RSA encryption.

For values of $x=2^k$ where $128 \le k \le 4096$ this function is nearly linear in $k$, with a 10-fold increase in the ratio for every 26 bits added to the number.

So, the first part of my question is: Is this analysis correct and accurate?

The second question is: what's the point in doing multiple rounds of Miller-Rabin when searching for primes of 1024 or more bits? The odds of ever picking a strong pseudoprime of this size so small as to be effectively zero.

Now, on the other hand, when searching for 1024-bit primes, if 710 (or maybe 1420) random values will have to be tested on average before finding a prime, the extra cost of running another 50 rounds of Miller-Rabin on a candidate that passes the first round is not all that much, so why not do that and be sure?

Being a little tongue in cheek, someone should offer a prize for the first person to publish a strong pseudoprime greater than $2^{1023}$, or $2^{2047}$. That would be a pretty safe bet wouldn't it? At least until some new technology like quantum compting enters the picture. Or put some code in openssl to flag the case where it finds a strong pseudoprime, proclaiming in effect, "*we have a winner!*"

Comment: Define "liar.".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm pretty sure OP here is referring to a (Miller-Rabin) [_pseudoprime_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime) .

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  Oh gee... *that* wasn't obvious at *all*!  Thanks.

Comment: The $1/4$ probability for a failure is only the worst case. If you pick up a random number with the magnitude you used and it passes the weak $2$-PRP test , the probability that it is a prime number is already very very close to $1$. If you take a random base in the range from $1$ to your given number , then the probability of a failure is virtually $0$ (Look at Chris Caldwell's prime page "Probable prime-how probable ?")

Comment: Note that the fact that a number is large does not prevent it to be a strong probable prime for many bases (in fact , every finite combination of bases still gives infinite many numbers for which the test fails). But that you hit such a number, is virtually impossible.

Comment: Another extremely reliable primality test is the BPSW-test. Incredibly, NO counterexample is known although it uses only one strong Fermat test and then one Lucas test depeding on the input.

Comment: I have re-written the original question in line with the helpful comments from folks. Let's start over from here now.

Comment: Strong pseudoprimes (of virtually arbitary size) can be constructed , so it makes no sense to offer a prize for finding such a number. If we want to be SURE that a number is prime, we have to apply , for example , the Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely test, although $50$ bases in Miller Rabin is more than enough in practice. The running time is reasonably small even for about $1\ 000$-digit numbers.

Comment: Peter, thanks for mentioning the BPSW test. The s/w code I am using is derived from an on-line example which uses the GNU big number library (gmp) to implement Miller-Rabin. Not having much experience with that library, I just tweaked the example code a bit to my liking. But, thanks to your comment I discovered that gmp has a built-in function to perform the BPSW test. I switched to that and things are running twice as fast now.